# How can I use UIWebView in Objective-C to display a Webpage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I've been trying to implement UIWebView into my application for a while now but when I do my application crashes upon startup.
 My code is:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *urlAdress=@"http://www.facebook.com";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAdress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

The Debugger says Thread 1: Stopped at breakpoint 4

Comment: Do you have a break point set that it is stopping on?  It will be a blue translucent bar next to the line number of the code it is on.

Comment: For any crash, you should always say what the exact error is and what line of code it is referring to.  In this case, it seems very likely that it has stopped at a breakpoint you have set!

Comment: @WayneHartman Its stops at NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAdress];

Comment: Can you post a screenshot, or a link to a screenshot of when you hit that point?

Comment: @WayneHartman Sure [link](http://t.co/aKJGQZmY)

Comment: Unfortunately, you did not include the portion of the screen immediately to the left, so as to hide whether a breakpoint is indeed set or not.  Just from the message, though, it would appear that a breakpoint is set.

Comment: @WayneHartman Sorry about that, I got a better shot this time [link](http://t.co/W6SRWU7q)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have breakpoints set.  See the blue arrow in the narrow column immediately left of your code?  You have three of them set.  You can disable the break point by clicking on the blue breakpoint arrow so that it dims (disabled).  You can remove the breakpoint by right clicking on the blue arrow and removing it.  A second way to remove it is to click and drag the breakpoint into the main window of your code, causing it to use the same dissolve animation used on the Mac OS X dock when you remove an item from it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I used to be a web programer but I decided to give iPhone Development a shot. Thanks for helping out a new guy